# Проверка на наличие в коллекции элемента в ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, observablecollection

есть такой вот метод

```
private void Update() {
        string extension = ".mp3";
        if (Directory.Exists(AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"\Downloaded")) {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"\Downloaded");
            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*" + extension, SearchOption.AllDirectories);
            foreach (var file in files) {
                var item = new MusicFile(file.FullName);
                var result = DownloadedFiles.Contains(item);
                if (result)
                    return;
                else
                DownloadedFiles.Add(item);                    
            }
        }
        Check(DownloadedFiles, PlayingMusic);
    }
```

Contains не возвращает true, если такой уже элемент есть в коллекции и каждый раз добавляет дубликаты или необходимо сравнивать по тегам?

класс MusicFile

```
public class MusicFile : ViewModelBase {
    private Guid _id;
    public Guid Id {
        get {
            return _id;
        }
        set {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Id));
        }
    }
    private string _title;
    /// <summary>
    /// Заголовок
    /// </summary>
    public string Title {
        get { return _title; }
        set {
            _title = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Title));
        }
    }
    private string _artist;
    /// <summary>
    /// Исполнитель
    /// </summary>
    public string Artist {
        get { return _artist; }
        set {
            _artist = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Artist));
        }
    }
    private string _album;
    /// <summary>
    /// Альбом
    /// </summary>
    public string Album {
        get { return _album; }
        set {
            _album = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Album));
        }
    }
    private string _poster;
    /// <summary>
    /// Постер
    /// </summary>
    public string Poster {
        get { return _poster; }
        set {
            _poster = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Poster));
        }
    }
    private string _duration;
    /// <summary>
    /// Длительность
    /// </summary>
    public string Duration {
        get { return _duration; }
        set {
            _duration = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Duration));
        }
    }
    private string _filePath;
    /// <summary>
    /// Путь к файлу (локальный)
    /// </summary>
    public string FilePath {
        get { return _filePath; }
        set {
            _filePath = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(FilePath));
        }
    }
    private string _source;
    /// <summary>
    /// Путь к файлу (внешний)
    /// </summary>
    public string Source {
        get { return _source; }
        set {
            _source = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Source));
        }
    }
    private string _url;
    /// <summary>
    /// Url файла
    /// </summary>
    public string URL {
        get { return _url; }
        set {
            _url = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(URL));
        }
    }
    private bool _liked;
    /// <summary>
    /// Статус файла (нравится или нет)
    /// </summary>
    public bool Liked {
        get { return _liked; }
        set {
            _liked = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Liked));
        }
    }
    private BitmapSource likedState;
    /// <summary>
    /// Тест 
    /// </summary>
    public BitmapSource LikedState {
        get {
            return likedState;
        }
        set {
            likedState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("LikedState");
        }
    }
    private bool _isPlay;
    /// <summary>
    /// Файл воспроизводится
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsPlay {
        get {
            return _isPlay;
        }
        set {
            _isPlay = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPlay));
        }
    }
    private bool _isPaused;
    /// <summary>
    /// Файл на паузе
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsPaused {
        get {
            return _isPaused;
        }
        set {
            _isPaused = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsPaused));
        }
    }
    private Location _location;
    /// <summary>
    /// Расположение файла
    /// </summary>
    public Location Location {
        get {
            return _location;
        }
        set {
            _location = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Location));
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление файла из сети
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title">Заголовок</param>
    /// <param name="artist">Артист</param>
    /// <param name="album">Альбом</param>
    /// <param name="poster">Постер</param>
    /// <param name="duration">Длительность</param>
    /// <param name="source">Путь к файлу (внешний)</param>
    /// <param name="url">Путь к странице с файлом</param>
    /// <param name="location">Расположение файла</param>
    public MusicFile(string title, string artist, string album, string poster, string duration, string source, string url, Location location) {
        _title = title;
        _artist = artist;
        _album = album;
        _poster = poster;
        _duration = duration;
        _source = source;
        _url = url;
        _location = location;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление файла локально (тест)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="title"></param>
    /// <param name="artist"></param>
    /// <param name="filepath"></param>
    public MusicFile(string title, string artist, string filepath) {
        _title = title;
        _artist = artist;
        _filePath = filepath;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Добавление файла локально и чтение информации из его тега
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">Путь к файлу</param>
    public MusicFile(string file) {
        getTitle(file);
        getArtist(file);
        getAlbum(file);
        getDuration(file);
        getPoster(file);
        getFilePath(file);
        getState(file);
        Location = Location.Local;
        Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Чтение из тега заголовка
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getTitle(string path) {
        var file = TagLib.File.Create(path);
        var title = file.Tag.Title;
        if (title == null)
            _title = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
        else
            _title = file.Tag.Title;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Чтение из тега артиста
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getArtist(string path) {
        var file = TagLib.File.Create(path);
        var art = file.Tag.FirstPerformer;
        if (art == null)
            _artist = "";
        else
            _artist = art.Replace("[mp3xa.cc]", "").Replace("&amp;", "&").Replace("[drivemusic.me]", "").Replace("[mp3xa.me]", "");
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Чтение из тега альбома
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getAlbum(string path) {
        var file = TagLib.File.Create(path);
        _album = file.Tag.Album;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Получить полный путь к файлу
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getFilePath(string path) {
        _filePath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(path);
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Получить из тега длительность
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getDuration(string path) {
        var duration = "00:00";
        if (path != null) {
            var file = TagLib.File.Create(path);
            duration = file.Properties.Duration.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
        }
        _duration = duration;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Стандартный постер файла
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="path">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getPoster(string path) {
        _poster = $@"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}/Images/file.png";
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Проверка на лайк
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file">Путь к файлу</param>
    private void getState(string file) {
        if (Liked) {
            LikedState = new BitmapImage(new Uri(AppContext.BaseDirectory + @"/Images/like.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        } else {
            LikedState = null;
        }
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        var item = obj as MusicFile;
        if (item == null) {
            return false;
        }
        return this.Id == item.Id;
    }
    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return this.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: `MusicFile` покажите. Наверняка `Equals` и `GetHashCode` не переопределены.

Comment: Прочитав ваш ответ, попробовал переопределить эти методы, но видимо я не до конца понял как они должны работать. Возможно надо сравнивать хеш файлов, но как пока не додумался. На всякий случай добавил в вопрос класс MusicFile.

Comment: Абстрагируйтесь от файлов. Вот у вас есть условно 2 класса человека, один `new Person("Вася")`, другой `new Person("Петя")`. Это разные классы? Да. Ок, а если мы сделаем два раза `var p1 = new Person("Маша"); var p2 = new Person("Маша");` - это одинаковые классы? Нет. Почему? Ну вот перед вами стоит две Маши, два разных человека, с разной внешностью, повадками и прочим, может такое быть? Да. Ну вот и в мире классов такое может быть. Когда вы пишете `DownloadedFiles.Contains(new MusicFile(file.FullName));`, вы пытаетесь в коллекции найти **новый** объект, который только что создали.

Comment: Как быть? Да все очень просто, либо ищите по значению (допустим прост `DownloadedFiles.Any(x=>x.Name == item.Name);`, либо как сказали выше, переопределяйте `Equals`, чтоб у вас сверялись данные класса. Студия кстати сама умеет генерировать это, достаточно нажать на класс и там в всплывающем окне будет опция генерации.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, все получилось. Переопределил Equals и проверяю путь к файлу. На данный момент такое решение подойдет мне.